# quadRotor odom. options (single camera?)

Tags: quadcopter, slam, navigation, odometry, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a quadrotor with the following sensors:
: sparton IMU
: hokuyo URG
: forward facing camera
: downward facing camera

I've messing around with hector_slam using the IMU and the laser range finder.  The problem is that when It goes down a relatively featureless environment (such as a bare hallway) it doesn't notice that it is moving.  This of course causes problems with the mapping.

I know that it is technically possible to use IMU data to create odom data, however I also know that it can become completely unusable due to error in a few seconds.

My main question is if any of you know of a way which takes a single camera and finds odom data.  Any suggestions for a possible solution would be great.

(I'm on fuerte)

Thank you,
Price

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64177/quadrotor-odom.-options-(single-camera?)/) by [price13](https://answers.ros.org/users/4871/price13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use a single camera u need to use some VSLAM algorithm to estimate the position of quadrotor and build a map. PTAM is one such algorithm. http://ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_ptam

You can try this package.

Hope it helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1